# What gives a porter or a stout its dark colour?

Tags: colour

I imagine it's probably just that the barley has been roasted darker, and that comes out.

Comment: Because the barley is burnt (i.e. "carbonized," as another poster stated)

Answer (score 10):

If you follow the information trail through Wikipedia's [page about Stout beer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stout), you find that what was known as Stout became a strong, dark beer in the 1800s:

> In the 19th century, the beer gained its customary black colour through the use of black patent malt, and became stronger in flavour.

You can see from the [article about mash ingredients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mash_ingredients#Black_malt) that black patent malt is "barley malt that has been kilned to the point of carbonizing, around 200 °C." It is apparently called "patent" malt because the inventor was awarded a patent for it.

Sometimes, this malt is used to darken the colour of other beers.

Answer (score 5):

You're right - is the high kilning temperatures used in the malt that give it a dark color.

Note that not all Stouts use black patent malt - some use roasted unmalted barley, most famously, Guinness, which uses 18% roasted barley in the recipe (IIRC from my trip to the brewery.) If you look through a pint of Guinness, you'll see that it's not simply jet black, but in fact fairly clear, and the light will give ruby highlights to the beer.